# reactjs how to filter / check if a any object in an array is present in another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

im facing the issue when trying to implement some conditional rendering. Here is the context:

## the data:

```
groups_a : [
             {id:1} ,
             {id:2}
            ]

groups_b : [
             {id:1} ,
             {id:3}
            ]
```

## The condition:

I wish to be check each item in groups_b , whether they exist in groups_a . So in this case , the condition should return back `true` because groups_b has `id:1` and so does groups_a

## JSX :

```
            {###the condition ##
                         ?
            <Button>Approve</Button>   
            :
            null
            }
```

Comment: Both groups seems to be object (with incorrect syntax), it should be enclosed in [] instead of {}

Comment: `groups_a` and `groups_b` are not valid **JavaScript** objects. Are you sure those variables are not type of [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)? Which would make more sense.

Comment: Hello i apologize , yes it should be an array , have updated my question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this assuming groupA/groupB to be array of object

```js
const groupA = [{id:1}, {id:3}, {id:4}];
const groupB = [{id:1}, {id:3}];

const boolean = groupB.every(obj => groupA.find(aObj => obj.id === aObj.id));
console.log('Method 1:', boolean)
// this will be true if every object in B is included in A

// If these are extremely large arrays you can improve performance by converting groupA into obj, and then checking by that object

const groupAHashMap = groupA.reduce((acc, cur) => ({...acc, [cur.id]: true}), {});
const boolean2 = groupB.every(obj => groupAHashMap[obj.id]);
console.log('Method 2:', boolean2)
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use the find to return true if at least one is present?

Comment: @neowenshun if u want the answer one only one is present then just replace every with some, groupB.some(obj => groupA.find(aObj => obj.id === aObj.id)

Comment: the second solution returns false ! @ehab

Comment: @HamidShoja yea thx for spotting the error, i forgot to add the initial accumulator for the reduce function

Answer (score 0):

checkout this

```
function App(){ 

    const groupA = [{id:1}, {id:2}];
    const groupB = [{id:1}, {id:3}];

    const gourpAIds = groupA.map(item => item.id);

    return groupB.map(item => {
        if(gourpAIds.includes(item.id)){
            return <Button>Approve</Button>   ;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it's an other solution that you can get the common list also.

```js
const groupA = [{id:1}, {id:3}, {id:4}];
const groupB = [{id:1}, {id:2}];



const ListCommon = groupA.filter(x => groupB.find(y => x.id === y.id));

console.log('result:', ListCommon.length>0)
console.log('List:', ListCommon)
```